# Sending message in react.js returns id instead of message

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a community chat page on my business website. I am using firebase firestore to make the messages realtime but whenever I hit the send button it returns an id instead of the actual message the user types in the text box.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import db from "../firebase";
import InputBar from "./InputBar";
import Message from "./Message";
import firebaseApp from "../firebase";
import "../styles/Chat.css";

const Chat = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("messages").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setMessages(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          message: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    db.collection("messages").add({
      message: input,
    });

    setMessages([
      ...messages, input
    ]);
    setInput("");
  };

  //   setTimeout(() => {
  //     const chat = document.querySelector("#chat");
  //     chat.scroll({ behavior: "smooth" });
  //     chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
  //   }, 500);

  const scrollToMessage = () => {
    const chat = document.querySelector("#messages");
    
    chat.scroll({ behavior: "smooth" });
    chat.scrollBottom = -chat.scrollHeight;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToMessage();
  }, [messages])

  return (
    <div className="chat-card overflow-y-scroll shadow-md mx-auto p-5 w-10/12 h-4/6 my-24">
      <h1 className="text-white text-center font-bold text-lg">
        Community Chat
      </h1>

      <div className="my-5 mx-auto">
        <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}
            className="w-full py-2 rounded"
            type="text"
          />
          <button className="w-full text-white font-bold my-2 rounded bg-red-500 py-2">
            SEND
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="messages" className="messages">
      {
        messages.map((id, message) => {
          return ( 
            <Message key={id} msg={message} />
          )
        })
      }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

these are the two firebase parts:

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("messages").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setMessages(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          message: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
```

I am guessing this is where the bug is:

```
  const sendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    db.collection("messages").add({
      message: input,
    });

    setMessages([
      ...messages, input
    ]);
    setInput("");
  };
```

Any help would be awesome!

Here is what I get when I console.log(messages):

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState(["hello", "goodbye"]);

useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("messages").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      console.log(messages);
      setMessages(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          message: doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
        }))
      );
    });
    console.log(messages);
  }, []);
```

result:

```
array(2)
array(2)
```

error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {message, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the map args reversed. It should be...

```
messages.map((message, id) => {
  return ( 
    <Message key={id} msg={message} />
  )
})
```

Comment: I tried that and I always get error "If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.". I have a question that covers this but none of the answers work.

Comment: You must have another issue. The code above works... https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-noether-bv7yv

Comment: Well yeah it works without any of the firebase database stuff. It must be a firebase problem.

Comment: @Caleb what is the value of `messages`? Can you add that content to your question?

Comment: I set the value of messages in the useEffect on line 14. The value of "message" is doc.data() which is whatever is stored in the firebase database. I was following a github repository https://github.com/leopaul29/facebook-messenger-clone/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: Right, I understand that. I mean, can you show the actual contents of `messages`? The only way the above solution doesn't work is if `messages` doesn't have the format you expect. Maybe add `console.log(messages)` right before the `map` call and see what you have.

Comment: I get "array(0)" or just "[]". But I keep getting stupid error. this time the error is a bit different though. it says -> " Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {message, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.". I am sorry if this does not help.

Comment: Seems like you logged `messages` before it was populated... it's an empty array. We need to see what's in it after it's populated.

Comment: Well it is not possible to see what happens when it is populated with whatever is typed in the input bar but I populated it with hard coded data and I get "array(2)" (with the contents I populated it with). It says "array(2)" before and after "setMessages(snapshot.docs,map()...)".

Comment: Why is it not possible? Try putting `console.log(message)` inside of the `map` loop.

Comment: Because the error happens before I can interact with the website. And I just did and it comes back with "{message: {…}, id: "8bE8FPxTeTgC6V3eRrer"}"

Comment: Right that's what we're looking for. The `message` value is an object... it's not a string. That's the problem. Everytime you call `setMessages` you need to make sure you're populating `messages` with what you want. So here `message: doc.data(),`... check out what `doc.data()` is. It's probably an object.

Comment: When I console.log(doc.data()) it returns an object. I thank you so much for your help! But I really cannot find answers online or on there official documentation. doc.data() should work fine but it doesn't.

Comment: What's in that object? Maybe it's the fields from your db table. You should be able to see what to do with it. Does that object looks like `{message: ..., ...}`?

Comment: It says -> "{id: "8bE8FPxTeTgC6V3eRrer", message: ƒ}"

Comment: Maybe try `doc.data().message()`.

Comment: I sort of fixed it by doing JSON.stringify(doc.data()) but it returns it as {"messag": "my_message"} is there any way to make it a little prettier or is this just how stringify works.

Comment: I recommend looking at the documentation for wherever that data is coming from, or asking whoever is responsible for creating that. Otherwise you'll probably end up guessing and/or doing a bunch of unnecessary work.